# Ad block plus not working

Tags: firefox, adblock

It seems as though Ad block plus has stopped working. I'm using Firefox 32.0.3 and Abp 2.6.4 and Element Hiding Helper 1.3

For example [this](http://www.ranker.com/list/full-list-of-jeep-models/reference) page seems to have more ads than it should. Here's [example](http://www.hrtwarming.com/at-first-she-thought-it-was-a-prank-call-but-her-quick-thinking-saved-a-life-this-is-genius/) with an ad. [Another](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/7153/frequency-division-multiplexing-fdm).

I unchecked allow some unobtrusive ads. The question is how do I get it to block these ads or what is the next step in trouble shooting? It used to work much better.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Xavierjazz how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling adblock plus (abp) and re-installing it? Even if ABP is working, would that advertisement qualify to be blocked?

Comment: @sunk818 I see your point about the advertisement qualifying to be blocked, all I can say is I've seen a very noticeable increase of advertisements not being blocked.

Comment: Sure, that's a valid observation. You just need to make sure that the adblocker is supposed to block it and it is not being blocked. I thought ABP on Firefox had a lot more features to detect stuff like. I use Chrome so I haven't used ABP on Firefox in some years...

Comment: What have you already tried? Reinstalled the add-on already? Does it work on other browsers? What's your operating system to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Adblock Edge](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-edge/) instead of Adblock Plus.

> Adblock Edge is a fork of the Adblock Plus version 2.1.2 extension for blocking advertisements on the web. This fork will provide the same features as Adblock Plus 2.X and higher but without "**acceptable ads**" feature.

See [Adblock Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus#Controversy_over_ad_filtering_and_ad_whitelisting) for more information regarding **acceptible ads**

Comment: Ok I'm giving Adblock Edge a try now. Do you know if it's supposed to work while in private browsing mode? I did notice that in it google ads weren't blocked, however in regular mode they were (but this was right after installing the adon so it may be a pathological example).

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I've never used private browsing :/

Answer (score 2):

So have you checked that you have an appropriate filter list subscription for the ad in question? Adblock Plus, by itself, blocks nothing, and someone, either yourself or the authors of a premade filter list (such as EasyList) must write a filter rule that blocks the ad. It is a huge and neverending game of catchup to keep up with the constantly changing
web technology that websites use to show ads.

The appropriate thing to do if you find an ad that should be blocked, but isn't, is to notify the filter list authors. [EasyList, for instance, has a user forum for exactly that purpose](http://forums.lanik.us/index.php). [AdBlock Plus also has a forum section for that purpose](https://adblockplus.org/forum/). Your AdBlock Plus button on the toolbar has a menu item called "Report Issue on this Page ... " that is there for exactly that purpose. I suggest you use it. The popular filter list authors are very quick to fix such issues when they are reported by users.